# Update a PowerPivot in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Stored Procedure and I need to put the result in a PivotTable. The SP has two date values as paramenters. I want a macro button to take the two paramenters (each one in a different cell), execute the SP and update the PivotTable in a Excel spreadsheet.

I have a macro that takes the parameters and updates the table with the result of the SP and automatically refreshes a Pivot Table based on the table.

```
Sub Atualizar()
    Dim lDataIni As String
    Dim lDataFim As String
    'Obtem os dados do parêmetro para consulta
    lDataIni = "'" & Format(Sheets("ViewHistorico").Range("C1").Value, "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:SS") & "'"
    lDataFim = "'" & Format(Sheets("ViewHistorico").Range("C2").Value, "yyyyMMdd 23:59:59") & "'"

    Sheets("Dados").Select
    'executa a consulta na planilha Dados para popular a tabela
    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query from dbDW").ODBCConnection
        .BackgroundQuery = False 'False para forçar a espera da atualização do PowerPivot
        .CommandText = Array("EXEC SpHistoricoCobrancaProdutor " & lDataIni & " , " & lDataFim)
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .Connection = Array(Array( _
        "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 11.0;SERVER=dbDW;UID=efritsch;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Office 2013;WSID=C3" _
        ), Array("1089;DATABASE=DW;"))
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .SavePassword = False
        .SourceConnectionFile = ""
        .SourceDataFile = ""
        .ServerCredentialsMethod = xlCredentialsMethodIntegrated
        .AlwaysUseConnectionFile = False
    End With
    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query from dbDW")
        .Name = "Query from dbDW"
        .Description = ""
    End With

    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

    'Atualiza o PowerPivot com base na planilha Dados que foi atualizadas
    Sheets("ViewHistorico").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotCache.Refresh

    MsgBox ("Atualizado com sucesso!")

End Sub
```

What I really want is a macro button that updates the PivotTable without necessity of other table.

Comment: It looks like your code already does everything you want, but you want to connect it to a command button?  Or do you want to perform the pivot table update without running the stored procedure?

Comment: @PeterT I have two sheets, one called "Dados". In that contains the result of running the stored procedure. The pivot table is in the sheet called "ViewHistorico" and in that is updated based in the sheet "Dados". I want the pivot table be updated by the SP without the sheet "Dados". That's clear?

Comment: Since pivot tables are based on data (with an internal link object called a `PivotCache`), the only real way to update the pivot table is to update the data. In your case, updating the data (on "Dados") involves running the SP. Microsoft has defined pivot tables to only be updated through the source data. Your only other option is to have your SQL query return data and you manually format it to a different worksheet.